# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number happens for a left join

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

```
$teacherStats = DB::table( DB::raw("({$payableContracts->toSql()}) as payable") )
        ->select('payable.teacher_id')
        ->selectRaw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as full_name,
            SUM(total_direct_benefit + total_indirect_benefit) AS total_benefit,
            SUM(teachers_direct_share + teachers_indirect_share) as teachers_share"
        )
        ->selectRaw("DATE('$wageFrom') as wage_from, DATE('$wageTo') as wage_to") 
        ->mergeBindings($payableContracts)
        ->join('users', 'payable.teacher_id', 'users.id')
        ->groupBy('payable.teacher_id')

$result = DB::table(DB::raw("({$teacherStats->toSql()}) as stats"))
        ->leftJoin('teacher_wages', function ($join) use ($wageFrom, $wageTo){
            $join->on('stats.teacher_id', '=', 'teacher_wages.teacher_id')
                ->where('teacher_wages.from', $wageFrom)
                ->where('teacher_wages.to', $wageTo)
                ->where('teacher_wages.contracts_type', 'percentage-based');
        });
```

I have $teacherStats as a query and when I get and dd() the result of it, it just works fine. This query is a complicated one but the result is as simple as:

```
 [▼
  0 => {#591 ▼
    +"teacher_id": 2
    +"full_name": "Tom Cruz"
    +"total_benefit": "126000"
    +"teachers_share": "25200"
    +"wage_from": "2020-04-01"
    +"wage_to": "2020-04-03"
  }
  1 => {#594 ▼
    +"teacher_id": 5
    +"full_name": "John Reno"
    +"total_benefit": "296000"
    +"teachers_share": "103600"
    +"wage_from": "2020-04-01"
    +"wage_to": "2020-04-03"
  }
]
```

The problem is with the above $result query which converts $teacherStats to sql as an alias and does a simple join with another table. I get this error:

**SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number**

without a clue to what parameter and number it refers to.

Comment: why are you using that raw clause?

Comment: plz post the `$teacherStats` query code

Comment: `->selectRaw("DATE('$wageFrom') as wage_from, DATE('$wageTo') as wage_to") ` this line has sql injection problem

Comment: and try to apply `mergeBindings($teacherStats)` to result

Comment: @TsaiKoga Yes, actually applying mergeBindings worked! Thank you! But there is a new problem. I get an empty result even though I'm doing a left join. I expect to get all columns of teacherStats when the join condition is not met (and get null values for teache_wages columns).

Comment: try to use `->toSql()` or `DB::getQueryLog()` to see the raw sql.

Comment: @TsaiKoga and about the injection problem: I use this code in my website admin panel. So end-user doesn't have access to it at all. Is it fine in this way?

Comment: if someone try to  request with `$wageFrom`, which value is like `'2020-01-01'); Drop table teacher_wages; -- ` , it may drop the table in your db.